# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0 : no new solution

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-5

I've developed an application using Entity Framework 5 and published to Azure. When running it from Visual Studio 2015, it works fine. However, when running it from Azure, I get the following error, 'Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0'. Below is part of the connection string (username and password excluded).

name="KnowledgeWikiEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.WikiModel.csdl|res://*/Models.WikiModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.WikiModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=[server name];initial catalog=[table name];user id=[username];password=[password];MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

I've looked through several different solutions, but none have worked. Any ideas about why this problem is occurring?

Comment: What version of .net is your Azure site running?

Comment: It was using v4.6  I changed the version of the solution on VS 2015 to 4.6 from 4.5, published the change and still got the same results.